# permitted_params - rails4 and inherited_resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, inherited-resources

I've tried to use IR in rails4 app, but my code

```
class WorkspacesController < InheritedResources::Base

  private

  def permitted_params
    params.permit(:workspace => [:name, :owner_id])
  end
end
```

raises ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError exception.

the same problem with following code

```
  def permitted_params
    params.permit(:name, :owner_id)
  end
```

Whats wrong with this code?

PS: i've tried following protip http://blog.josemarluedke.com/posts/inherited-resources-with-rails-4-and-strong-parameters but with 4.0rc1 it doesn't work :(

Comment: Can you post the params? Have you tried params.require(:workspace).permit(:name, :owner_id)?

Comment: Is this the preferred solution for rails 4.0.0 final? I've checked the issue tracker but haven't seen any definitive approach on how to get rid of protected_attributes when using inherited_resources.

Comment: This worked: http://joshcrews.com/blog/2013/09/05/getting-inherited-resources-gem-to-work-with-strong-parameters/

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.

You need to put permitted_params method as public method in your controller class. It's NOT a private method.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

I have meet this problem too, but seem not same as yours, just put how I resolve this in case some meet same problem with mine

replace Gemfile with this

```
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
```